# Why are my user uploaded photos not finding the proper directory on the server?

Tags: php, apache

I am attempting to give users the ability to upload their own profile pictures for their accounts, but the photos they upload seem to never find their proper destination. I have followed tutorials from [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_file_uploading.htm), a couple of different StackOverflow threads and have gone into my php.ini file to configure it to allow file uploads.

Here is the abridged code I'm using for the form

```
<form method="post" action="db/update-account" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="profPic" accept="image/jpeg, image/png">
<input type="submit" value="Save Changes"/>
```

and this is what the PHP script looks like

```
if(isset($_FILES['profPic'])) {
   $errors = array();
   $file_name = $_FILES['profPic']['name'];
   $file_size = $_FILES['profPic']['size'];
   $file_tmp = $_FILES['profPic']['tmp_name'];
   $file_type = $_FILES['profPic']['type'];
   $file_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['profPic']['name'])));

   $extensions = array("jpeg","jpg","png");

   if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions) === false) {
       $errors[] = "extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
   }

   if($file_size > 2097152) {
       $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
   }

   if(empty($errors) == true) {
       move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"imgs/profile-pics/custom".$file_name);
   } else {
       print_r($errors);
   }
}
```

Any tips in the right direction would be extremely appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Do you need a slash after `custom` in your path? I am also going to advise against using `$_FILES['profPic']['name']` raw.

Comment: @Scuzzy I don't know how I didn't catch that, but that did it. Thank you so much :D